# apache exited unexpectedly and chrome browser failed without any response

Tags: php, angular, apache, yii2

i have an angular application with Yii2 restful , when i load application there are a lot of resources with multiple rest api requests at the first.
sometimes a rest api failed with (failed) status and net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in chrome browser. when an api request failed all other api requests also failed.

i'm using windows , apache , php 7.1 (xampp)
also i have same problem with linux and nginx

my apache error log :

```
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:12.832792 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH00428: Parent: child process 11936 exited with status 3221226356 -- Restarting.
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.038794 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.061795 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2n PHP/7.1.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.061795 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 22 2018 10:55:30
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.061795 2018] [core:notice] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.064796 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3392:tid 508] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3312
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.595807 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3312:tid 440] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.708809 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 3312:tid 440] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Oct 09 11:16:13.731810 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3312:tid 440] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

[error image in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/witRv.png)

I think it is about ThreadStackSize of apache but i can't increase it.

Is there anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found answer , it was about yii2 logging stack, when multiple requests sent to server concurrently, there were a lot of log stack that kept until the request ended then yii2 saved logs to database .
Also debugger module keeps logs until end of request.
When i decreased stack size of logs, requests executed correctly.
another way to solving this problem is changing db session to file session but i think its not good idea because we lose the speed and performance to executing requests.